# how to take integer input in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, input, converters

Ok so i am making a website which converts kilometer to meter and i take the input when a button is clicked and i take the input with the help of javascript my code is working but in the input box you can even write alphabets which i don't want i want the input box to just accept numeric letters
my code

```
document.getElementById("button1").addEventListener("click",function ktm(){
    let ktm1=window. prompt("Enter kilometer's value: ");
    alert(ktm1+" kilometer in meters would be "+ktm1*1000+" meters") ;
})
```

Comment: nothing you can do about it in a `prompt` - use an `<input type="number"` along with code that actively prevents you from even pasting non numbers into it

Comment: With `prompt`, all you can do is validate the input after the fact and prompt the user again if the input was not numeric.

Comment: bravo I want it to popup when clicked i also know that I can do it that way but it would be messy

Comment: deceze can you give the code to prompt the user again if the input was not numeric.

Comment: @MuhammadJamil You could try to make a input type=number and then use that as the input for your JS. Then just use `document.getElementById("TotalKilometer").value` on the input.

Comment: You cannot prevent people from inserting invalid values but you can keep prompting them for input until the value they type is valid (e.g. with a `do... while` loop). Something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/2m0pf9w7/

Comment: secan it worked!